# Stick element to bottom-right corner (AS3 - Adobe AIR)?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, resize, air

I'm creating a simple AIR app with resize-functionality. Of course i need to position a resize-arrow to the bottom-right corner. Here's my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, handleResize);
function handleResize(e:Event):void{
    resize_btn.y = stage.stageHeight-resize_btn.height;
}
```

This doesn't work, my button gets out of the window very quickly. How could I make this work?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set the stage scale and align modes.
Therefore, when you resize, the button goes to the desired Y but as the stage is centered it goes offscreen, giving the idea it's not working.

Try using this:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the ScaleMode but not the align.

Answer (score 0):

Does it fall out of the window vertically or horizontally?

You might want to set

`resize_btn.x = stage.stageWidth-resize_btn.width;`

this may be your problem.